# Android: Expandlelist with text and button in button

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

I am creating this exapandlelist which work okay. But now am I interest in creating button at the button of the page. It seems like the code clear all layout and create a new. So when I add a button text or other this is removed.

How can I prevent the layout for being removed?

The code are from: http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/android-expandablelistview-example.html

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //gemmer sidste tilstand

        // Create Expandable List and set it's properties
        ExpandableListView expandableList = getExpandableListView(); 
        expandableList.setDividerHeight(2);
        expandableList.setGroupIndicator(null);
        expandableList.setClickable(true);

        // Set the Items of Parent and child
        prepareListData();

        // Create the Adapter
        adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(parentParam, childItems);
        //setListAdapter(adapter);

        //ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), this);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // Set the Adapter to expandableList
        expandableList.setAdapter(adapter);
        expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(this);

    }
```